# Looping through nested dictionary values to populate second dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, statistics

I have the following dictionary:

```
rts = {
         "PO1": {
                   "congruent": {

                             "rt": [0.647259, 0.720116, 0.562909, 0.538918, 0.633367],
                        "correct": ["True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False",]
                             },

                  "incongruent": {

                             "rt": [0.647259, 0.720116, 0.562909, 0.538918, 0.633367],
                        "correct": ["True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False",]

                             }
         },
         "PO2": {
                   "congruent": {

                             "rt": [0.647259, 0.720116, 0.562909, 0.538918, 0.633367],
                        "correct": ["True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False",]
                             },

                  "incongruent": {

                             "rt": [0.647259, 0.720116, 0.562909, 0.538918, 0.633367],
                        "correct": ["True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False",]

                             }
         }
}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import json
import numpy as np
from numpy import array


def main():
    rts = {}
    statsDict = {}

    data = Path('C:/Users/oli.warriner/Desktop/data(2)/data')

    for csvfile in data.glob('*.csv'):
        key = csvfile.stem

        with csvfile.open() as f:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

            # Skip the header
            _ = next(csv_reader)

            rts[key] = {
                'congruent': {
                    'rt': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
                'incongruent': {
                    'rt': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
            }

            for tn, ctext, cname, condition, response, rt, correct in csv_reader:
                rts[key][condition]['rt'].append(float(rt))
                rts[key][condition]['correct'].append(correct)


    for k in rts:
        key = k
        statsDict[key] = {
                'congruent': {
                    'mean': [],
                    'stddev': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
                'incongruent': {
                    'mean': [],
                    'stddev': [],
                    'correct': []
                },
            }
        for n in rts[k]:
            for i in rts[key][n]

    array([rts[k] for k in rts]).mean()
    print(array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am reading a directory of csv files to produce the "rts" dictionary you see above (Its much bigger than that I have just shortened for here).

What I am now looking to do is to use the "rts" dictionary to populate the "statsDict".

I need to loop through the "rts" dictionary and calculate the mean and standard deviation from the "rt" values in both the "congruent" and "incongruent" values for each key separately.

I then need to use the boolean values in "correct" for each key to calculate a percentage of true in each one.

I am managing to loop through the first couple of layers on the dictionary however now I am a little lost I'm not sure how to go into the next layer down and begin making the stats calculations I need.

Hope this is clear enough for people. Let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the input you give! Why there is a `"congruent"` entry twice for every `"PO*"` entry?

Comment: @SimonFink My apologies! Well spotted, I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Another hint. When trying to give a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can leave out, how you create `rts`. The example data is sufficient. Please concentrate on what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example of `rts` given, you can construct a dictionary with statistics with this code fragment:

```
import statistics
import json

rts = { ... as given ... }

stats_dict = {}
for k in rts.keys():
    stats_dict[k] = {}
    for ck in rts[k].keys():
        stats_dict[k][ck] = {}
        stats_dict[k][ck]["mean"] = statistics.mean(rts[k][ck]["rt"])
        stats_dict[k][ck]["stdev"] = statistics.stdev(rts[k][ck]["rt"])    
        stats_dict[k][ck]["true_percentage"] = len([x for x in rts[k][ck]["correct"] if x == "True"]) / len(rts[k][ck]["correct"])

print(json.dumps(stats_dict, indent=2))
```

### Notes

- You do not necessarily need `numpy` to calculate the staticstis. The built-in `statistics` package is sufficient
- You do not need to initialize the dictionary in advance. Just make use of the keys of the given dictionary `rts` and use the same keys for the statisics dictionary `stats_dict`

### Output

```
{
  "PO1": {
    "congruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "incongruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    }
  },
  "PO2": {
    "congruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "incongruent": {
      "mean": 0.6205138,
      "stdev": 0.07207165926839758,
      "true_percentage": 0.8333333333333334
    }
  }
}
```